# how to get values from nested JSON object in ajax with c#

Tags: c#, ajax, nested, elixir-jason

JSON result is coming as below.

```
{
  "id": 8,
  "name": "ads",
  "productCategoryMappings": [
    {
      "id": 3,
      "categoryId": 21,
      "productId": 8,
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I access `categoryId` in AJAX success

I can access `result.name` but can not access `result.productCategoryMappings.categoryId`

Comment: `result.productCategoryMappings` is an array. You need access it with index. For example: `result.productCategoryMappings[0].categoryId`.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
result.productCategoryMappings[0].categoryId
```

Comment: It worked thanks a lot @Serge. I got the value.